# sed repetitions \+ not working on macOS but + works on linux

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed

I have a file with content: `<meta name="Description" content="The official site ......">`

and I try to use **sed** command to change it to: `<meta name="hello" content="The official site ......">`

`sed -i -E 's/Descript[^"]\+/hello/g' index.html`

but it didn't work, I change it to:

`sed -i -E 's/Descript[^"]*/hello/g' index.html`

it works, why the repetitions `\+` not working? (I also tried `+`)

**Edit:**

I am using OSX El Capitan, I just tried `sed -i -r 's/Descript[^"]+/hello/g'` on a linux (ubuntu and fedora), it works.

on linux it says:

> -r, --regexp-extended
>
> ```
>           use extended regular expressions in the script.
> ```

on OSX it says:

> -E      Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular
>                expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The
>                re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats.

**Edit:**

and here it get more weird:

```
danny:~ mac$ echo '<meta name="Description" content="The official....' | sed  -E 's/Descript[^"]+/hello/' 
<meta name="hello" content="The official....
danny:~ mac$ 
danny:~ mac$ echo '<meta name="Description" content="The official....' | sed  -E 's/Descript[^"]\+/hello/' 
<meta name="Description" content="The official....
```

Comment: Another possibility is `[^"][^"]*` since the quantified expression is relatively short.

Comment: @stribizhev `-E`is ERE

Comment: @123 it depends on which sed implementation.

Comment: @Kent if it isn't giving a syntax error then it's ERE.

Comment: `i just tried sed -i -r 's/Descript[^"]\+/hello/g' ... it works` are you sure?? `-r` for gnu sed is for ERE, then it won't work. using `+` (without `backslash`) will work.   `\+` will match literal "plus" sign.

Comment: @Kent sorry,typo, just change it

Comment: @123 weird is, OP said he tried both `\+` and `+`... both don't work. I cannot imagine that. I don't have bsd sed to test... and interesting is, my gnu sed doesn't throw error msg when I gave `-E`, although in manpage/infopage no `-E` was as option explained.

Comment: @Kent i am sure that  i tried both . and both of them didn't work.

Comment: @dannynjust from your just updated test result, your first test do worked!

Comment: @Kent really? Mine throws an error on GNU. What version have you got? Also -E on El capitan or -r on GNU definitely work without the slash, so unless OP has downloaded some crazy broken sed, then they are doing something that they aren't telling us or have a typo or somethin.

Comment: @123 --version reports: `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Comment: In general (and for good reasons) I don't trust what the OP says. Can some test it on a Mac? Does it work with a plain `+`?

Comment: @Kent yes it works for the first test, but not on the file

Comment: @dannynjust you have to check the bsd sed's man page, what is for `gnu's -i (in place)`, you cannot combine options from two different implementations...

Comment: Of course the real problem is that you're trying to manipulate HTML/XML as a plain text file. Don't.

Comment: `sed -i.bak -E 's/Descript[^"]+/hello/g' index.html` works fine on OSX

Comment: Maybe it's reading -E as a filename ?

Comment: @anubhava it works for me too, it is true what 123 said  without the .bak a file `index.html-E` is created.but what does `If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved` mean with the `zero-length extension`

Comment: BSD `sed` requires an argument after `-i`. So even `sed -i '' -E 's/Descript[^"]+/hello/g' index.html` will also work.

Answer (score 1):

using `+` (without `backslash`) will work.   `\+` will match literal "plus" sign.
                    – Kent

BSD `sed` requires an argument after `-i`. So even `sed -i '' -E 's/Descript[^"]+/hello/g' index.html` will also work.
                    – anubhava

See [`man sed`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html), [`man re_format`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html), [Differences between sed on Mac OSX and other “standard” sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13716/43764)